# Reload cabal file from stack ghci?

Tags: haskell, cabal, haskell-stack, ghci

If I modify my cabal file to add a module, `:reload` doesn't pick that up. Is there a way to `:reload` as if I ran `stack ghci` anew without having to exit ghci?

Comment: You can use `:set` command from within GHCI to run GHC flags. You may do like `:set --package matrix` and then `:r`. Check [GHCI Options](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/ghci.html#the-set-and-seti-commands) and [Flags Reference -> 4.19.11 Packages](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.0.3/docs/html/users_guide/flag-reference.html)

Comment: Also [ghcid](https://github.com/ndmitchell/ghcid) is a very nice tool for Haskell development.There are many options that would allow you to reload or restart GHCI automatically when any file/directory gets updated. (`--reload` and `--restart` switches) [Here is a good example](https://binarin.ru/post/auto-reload-threepenny-gui/) and [a blog post on ghcid](https://www.parsonsmatt.org/2018/05/19/ghcid_for_the_win.html)